# 'From Name' in Salesforce Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

Need urgent help!

We're implementing Marketing Cloud triggered send feature in salesforce. We have used custom 'From' Name for the email sent out. Now triggered send is working fine interms of sending mail. But the 'From' name is getting changed to Record Owner automatically in salesforce. Not sure why this is happening. Request all to provide inputs here!

Comment: Are you using a dynamic from name in the Sender Profile? %%FromName%%

You should then be able to pass the value in the payload of the TSD call.

Comment: Yes, am using %%FromName%% in sender profile. But the issue is, once triggered send executes, then in Sales Cloud, the 'From Name' field of triggered send record is getting modified as 'Record Owner'. I've no idea why that is happening. Any inputs??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have AMPScript in your sender profile to determine the final friendly from name or from email address? That will not work when the email is based off of a data extension for the send.

Instead, create a content area that contains the AMPScript that determines the final value. Once you've done that, view the properties of the content area to get the numeric ID of the content area. Finally, go back to your sender profile setup and enter %%=TreatAsContentArea(ContentArea())=%% into the appropriate field. This will work.

If you are doing a calculation on both the from name and the from email address, you will need to create two different content areas to complete the effort.

Good luck!